# Can binomial test be used here?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution

I'm trying to know if I'm using the correct test. I'm taking a mock-up example, but let's say that I hypothesize that psychology students significantly prefer thriller movies to other types of movies (action, romance, drama, comedy, horror).

Thus, I ran an experiment in which I displayed three genres of movies, and asked subjects to choose the one they preferred. One of those genre was **for sure** a thriller movie. The two others were randomly drawn from the movie list above.

I was considering running a binomial test here, to see if thriller movie genre was indeed more chosen than other types of movie. Here's what it looks like on R:[image]

However, the fact that other movie genres were randomly drawn is making me doubtful about the test here. In a nutshell, my question is: can I use a binomial test here, knowing that I did not control for the two other items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a binomial test or the `binom.test` function is a good choice. It will answer the question, whether a thriller movie is going to be chosen more often then the given mix of other movies (action, romance, drama, comedy, horror).

Let's say people like action movies most and thriller movies second best. With this approach you might find that thriller is better then the mix of other movies but you may overlook, that thriller movies are only second best.

It will depend on your circumstances whether such an hypothesis/null-hypothesis makes sense or not. Note that the p-value will only be valid if you planned this analysis ahead of getting the data. If you perform it after you have already computed thriller movie's place/rank, then you might have to think about multiple testing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and good point regarding the possible limitation of this approach.